# My click function is running when it's not supposed to

Tags: javascript, jquery

So, basic setup, I have three divs, each of them holding different content which, when the page is loaded, is all hidden.  Ideally, the user clicks one of the divs, which expands that one and shows the content.  They click another div, the open one closes and the one they clicked opens.

The problem is, even though I'm expressly referencing the class I want clickable, my function is running on the class that is "unclickable".

EDIT: Added a jsfiddle for better illustration of what I'm trying to accomplish:
http://jsfiddle.net/ev5ew41q/

Here's my javascript:

```
$(function() {
   $('.notContent').click(function() {
       $(this).switchClass('notContent','isContent');
       $('.isContent').switchClass('isContent','notContent');
       });
});
```

The CSS for the notContent (among other things) hides the "[some stuff here]".  The javascript is supposed to switch "notContent" out for "isContent" on click, but nothing else.  I've tried using an if/else, same thing happens.  Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

[edited for bad grammar]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply changing the class will not unbind the handler. The handler binds to that element at runtime! A simple solution is really to just toggle the element clicked, and hide all the others:

```
$('.notContent').click(function() {
    $(this).toggle();
    $(".notContent").not(this).hide();
});
```

Comment: Ok, so the problem is that my event is still bound to the div, even if the class changes?  I added a jsfiddle to kind of explain what I'm trying to accomplish a little better.  I can't hide the notContent div outright, unfortunately, it needs to change classes.

EDIT: Figured it out!  Just needed to add $(this).unbind().  Thanks!

Comment: @ChrisPEditor If you really want to control it with the class name, you could always listen on a root element, e.g. `$(document).on('click', '.notContent', function() { ...`